# type string using xdotool without being typed on screen twice (type selection of fzf)

Tags: bash, xdotools

I'd like to select something in fzf and type that selection as command I can edit and eventually invoke. The solution might look like this:

```
seq 5 | sed "s/^/echo Testing /" | fzf | xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}"
```

but the output on terminal looks like:

```
[me@~~~_09:40:22 ~]$ seq 5 | sed "s/^/echo Testing /" | fzf | xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}"
echo Testing 3[me@~~~_09:40:26 ~]$ echo Testing 3
```

it works, but potentially long command will be printed twice. It's more like "issue" of xdotool. It types the text before calling command completed, that's why it's written first, then command completes and what was written is "duplicated" in prompt.

I'd like to know if it's somehow possible to lauch this demo command to get just:

```
[me@~~~_09:40:22 ~]$ seq 5 | sed "s/^/echo Testing /" | fzf | xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}"
[me@~~~_09:40:26 ~]$ echo Testing 3
```

I was trying to play with delays, nested commands, but I can't figure that out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever anything is typed in to the terminal it is echoed. This is what are seeing. When bash restarts it sets the terminal to raw in order to handle all the special characters and editing etc, and so also turns off echo. It then reads what `xdotool` has typed, and dutifully echoes it.

You can get round this by turning off echo before running `xdotool`, eg:

```bash
.. fzf | (stty -F /dev/tty -echo; xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}"; stty -F /dev/tty echo)
```

Note, instead of `xdotool`, you can also use ioctl `TIOCSTI`. There are several C sources and perl scripts to do this. Here's one with the `stty` included:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://superuser.com/a/1663171/458747
use strict;
eval 'sub TIOCSTI () {0x5412;}' unless defined(&TIOCSTI);
system('stty -F /dev/tty -echo');
my $str;
if($#ARGV<0){ $str = join("",<STDIN>); } # read stdin if no args
else{ $str = join(" ",@ARGV); }
foreach my $ch (split('',$str)){
  ioctl(STDOUT, &TIOCSTI, $ch) or die $!;
}
system('stty -F /dev/tty echo');
```

If you put this in a file `pushtype` you can avoid the `xargs` and just `...fzf|pushtype`.

Comment: wow. I supposed that this will be easier, this touched areas I know close to nothing about.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: just a comment for newbies like me: pipe to pushtype must not contain \n (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
(seq 5|fzf|xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}") > /dev/null
```

Or the other way around:

```
(sleep 1; echo "hello"|xargs -I{} xdotool type "{}")& > /dev/null; fzf
```

Or a better history search:

```
eval "$(fzf --bash)"
```

So you can search with `Ctrl+R`

Or launching something with the selection?

```
fzf --bind "enter:become(vi {})"
```